# A more detailed explanation of bindnetaddr?

Tags: corosync

Reading the documentation:

> bindnetaddr

> This specifies the network address the corosync executive should bind to.

> For example, if the local interface is 192.168.5.92 with netmask 255.255.255.0, set bindnetaddr to 192.168.5.0. If the local interface is 192.168.5.92 with netmask 255.255.255.192, set bindnetaddr to 192.168.5.64, and so forth.

> This may also be an IPV6 address, in which case IPV6 networking will be used. In this case, the full address must be specified and there is no automatic selection of the network interface within a specific subnet as with IPv4.

> If IPv6 networking is used, the nodeid field must be specified.

This doesn't really tell me anything.

If my machine has multiple physical network cards, or a bond with multiple vlans, do I have to set them all, or just the ones I'll be assigning ip addresses to?

From testing, it seems like it doesn't matter. Setting it to only 1 network still allows me to assign ip adresses to other ones.

Can someone give more detail on the purpose of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between bind, network (interface) and multicast addresses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/363436/what-is-the-difference-between-bind-network-interface-and-multicast-addresses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably found the answer by now, but in case anyone else comes across this, this Network Address (IP Address masked with the Subnet Mask) of the interface you would like.

If you have multiple interfaces in the same subnetwork, then you much use the actual IP Address.

There reason for using the network address use that you can then share there configuration between nodes, something you cannot do when you hard-code the interface's address.